# How can I get the key names of VK constants?

Tags: java, keyevent

For example, some magical function

```
public String function(int key) {}
```

so that

`function(KeyEvent.VK_A)` would return `"A"`

`function(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)` would return `"DOWN"`

`function(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA)` would return `"COMMA"`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...
I found `public static String getKeyText(int keyCode)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getKeyText(int keyCode)` on your `KeyEvent`